# Enclosing scope must be final with Java Streams

Tags: java

When trying to count the number of chars in a string using streams I get an error
"Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"
What do you use as a work around in this case? Would I just have to do it separately without looping it?
I'm a student and the task is decrypting Caesar cipher so freq analysis is part of this.

Thank you.

```
public static int[] freqAnalyse(String text) {
    int[] frequencies = new int[26];
    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    text = text.toUpperCase();
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        frequencies[i] = (int) text.chars().filter(k -> k == alphabet.charAt(i)).count();
    }
    return frequencies;
}
```

EDIT
This works, is this bad practice or just what it wants?
Thank you.

```
public static int[] freqAnalyse(String text) {
        int[] frequencies = new int[26];
        String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        text = text.toUpperCase();
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            final int j = i;
            frequencies[j] = (int) text.chars().filter(k -> k == alphabet.charAt(j)).count();
        }
        return frequencies;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those cases, You can also completely ignore the count variable `i` using iterator.
Here is **an other way** to do it:

```
        int[] frequencies = new int[26];
        String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        text = text.toUpperCase();
        for (char c : alphabet.toCharArray()) {
            frequencies[c-'A'] = (int)text.chars().filter(value -> value == c).count();
        }
```

Using only stream one liner:

```
    String upperCase = text.toUpperCase();
    alphabet.chars().forEach(ch -> frequencies[ch-'A'] = (int)upperCase.chars().filter(value -> value == ch).count());
```

Comment: Idk why I didn't think of your part 1 there, love the one liner though. Need to get better at using streams like this.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The *simplest* workaround is to copy `i` into a new variable.

```
 final int ii = i;
 frequencies[i] = (int) text.chars().filter(k -> k == alphabet.charAt(ii)).count();
```

Alternately, you could just store a variable for that character:

```
final char ch = alphabet.charAt(i);
frequencies[i] = (int) text.chars().filter(k -> k == ch).count();
```

Comment: Worked it out a second before seeing this, edited it as such. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try doing something like this :

```
public static int[] freqAnalyse(String text) {
    int[] frequencies = new int[26];
    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    text = text.toUpperCase();
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        final char c = alphabet.charAt(i);
        frequencies[i] = (int) text.chars().filter(k -> k == c).count();
    }
    return frequencies;
}
```